# Correctly formatting data for I2C (Wire.write)

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I am connecting multiple Arduino Mega units together to create a bank of IO all controlled by a master on an I2C bus.

I had it working with the slave populating a string with the status of the analog inputs etc. each separated by a colon. The string would then be looped through with a `Wire.write`.

The initial `reqNo` would tell the master which batch were being returned. E.g. batch 0 would be analog 0 - 5, batch 1 would be analog 6 - 11 etc.

It was all working, until further reading led me to an article that advocated against using strings due to memory usage and related issues. I have tried to refactor my code to avoid the use of strings however, now I am getting strings like this:

> :⸮:⸮:⸮:⸮:⸮:⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮W

returned instead of my expected output.

I think this is an encoding issue or similar? Could anyone please offer advice on what I'm doing wrong or another way of achieving this please. It's pretty important that the device functions for very long periods of time without reboots or any issues which is why I was pretty keen to remove Strings if this could cause issues.

Master code:

```
int i=0;
char res[32]="";
while(Wire.available()){
    char c=Wire.read();
    Serial.print(c);
    res[i]=c;
    i++;
}
```

Slave code:

```
void requestStatus(){
    int i;
    Wire.write(reqNo);

    if(reqNo==0){
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
            Wire.write(':');
            Wire.write(analogRead(i));
        }
    }else if(reqNo==1){
        for(i=6;i<12;i++){
            Wire.write(':');
            Wire.write(analogRead(i));
        }
    }else if(reqNo==2){
        for(i=12;i<16;i++){
            Wire.write(':');
            Wire.write(analogRead(i));
        }
    }
    reqNo++;
    if(reqNo==3){
        reqNo=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using `res` anywhere in the code, please provide complete example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code, first:

```
...
// master side
char c=Wire.read();
...
// slave side            
Wire.write(analogRead(i));
```

you are treating integer values as if they were [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded, they are not. You have to convert them to ASCII at some point (e.g. master side). Consider using `sscanf` or `snprintf` for conversion.

Second, you are not [NUL terminating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) a C string.

Answer (score 0):

`Wire.write(reqNo);` for instance will write a character of code 0 1 or 2, not the character '0' or '1' or '2' if this what you expected

Answer (score 0):

> It was all working, until further reading led me to an article that advocated against using strings due to memory usage and related issues.

I assume it was talking about the `String` objects and not c-strings (nul terminated char arrays).
Those use dynamic memory allocation and cause heap fragmentation. C-strings are usually statically allocated (`char res[32];`), and are cleaned up cleanly from the stack, if they are defined inside a function.

`write` only accepts a single byte, an array of bytes (or chars) with explicit length or a c-string.
Passing it an int will only convert it to a byte and only keep the lower 8 bits.

What you need is the ˙print˙ method. It converts integers to characters on the fly. It doesn't use `String` or c-strings.

You should replace all of your `Wire.write` with `Wire.print`.

Also in your master code, you are not nul terminating the `res` char array, which will cause problems, since there is no explicit end of the string. You should also make sure, you don't write more than 31 characters into it (nul terminator also counts as a character), and cause buffer overflow.